# How can I not add a class to a specific block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How not to add a class to a block that does not have a class of foot-items? When I click on "Link", still the foot-active class is added and removed, even though this foot-menu does not have a class of foot-items, like the b condition was written.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.foot-title', function(e){
    if ($('.foot-menu').hasClass('foot-items')) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('foot-active');
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.foot-active .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foot-menu foot-items">
  <div class="foot-title">
   <a href="#">More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="link">
      Lorem 1
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="link">
      Lorem 1
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="link">
      Lorem 1
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div><!-- .b-menu -->
 </div>

 <div class="foot-menu">
  <div class="foot-title">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I also tried through .each(), but it did not work out.

```
$('.foot-title').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('.foot-menu').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('foot-items')) {
                $(this).toggleClass('foot-active');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking for the class `foot-items` you need to do it based on the clicked element so you need to do:

```
$(this).parent()
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.foot-title', function(e){
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('foot-items')) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('foot-active');
      console.log(".foot-active added or removed");
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.foot-active .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foot-menu foot-items">
  <div class="foot-title">
   <a href="#">More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="link">
      Lorem 1
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="link">
      Lorem 1
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="link">
      Lorem 1
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div><!-- .b-menu -->
 </div>

 <div class="foot-menu">
  <div class="foot-title">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are wlecome

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.foot-items.foot-menu', function(e){
      $(this).toggleClass('foot-active');       
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.foot-active .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foot-menu foot-items">
  <div class="foot-title">
   <a href="#">More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="link">
      Lorem 1
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="link">
      Lorem 1
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="link">
      Lorem 1
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div><!-- .b-menu -->
 </div>

 <div class="foot-menu">
  <div class="foot-title">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

If your aim is to add click event only with class  `foot-items` and `foot-menu`, You can change your click event on `.foot-items.foot-menu`. No need to trigger it each time.